# Why is EclipseLink JPA generating a bad query for an @Transient List entity member?

Tags: postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

I have an entity like the following:

```
public class OrganizationUser {
   // stuff
   @Transient
   public List<ExternalUserLink> externalUserLinks;
}
```

My code is persisting a completely unrelated object, but I'm getting an exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "organizationuser_externaluserlink" does not exist
  Position: 217
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT t1.id, t1.VALUE1, t1.VALUE2 FROM ORGANIZATIONUSER_EXTERNALUSERLINK t0, EXTERNALUSERLINK t1 WHERE (((t0.organizationUser_id = ?) AND (t1.id = t0.externalUserLinks_id))
    bind => [e1bf9c52-71d0-11ec-9152-0242ac120006]
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="externalUserLinks" referenceClass=ExternalUserLink sql="SELECT t1.id, t1.VALUE1, t1.VALUE2 FROM ORGANIZATIONUSER_EXTERNALUSERLINK t0, EXTERNALUSERLINK t1 WHERE (((t0.organizationUser_id = ?) AND (t1.id = t0.externalUserLinks_id))"); nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "organizationuser_externaluserlink" does not exist
  Position: 217
Error Code: 0
```

ExternalUserLink is also an entity and does not have any annotated references to OrganizationalUser (it does contain a UUID called `orgUserId` that refers to the OrganizationalUser, but this is not mentioned in annotations).

In fact, there is no such table or entity, and the IDs between OrganizationalUser and ExternalUserLinks are not related in any way but EclipseLink seems to have inferred some kind of relationship despite the `@Transient` annotation.  (Let alone as to why this query would even be invoked for an unrelated flush).

What is going on and how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more digging it turns out my "I'm too smart for you IDE" decided to pull in `org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient` instead of the proper `javax.persistence.Transient`.  Since this is the wrong annotation with the same name, JPA took it upon itself to map this list to a new table.